# Converting Asp.net page to pdf with Itextsharp (XMLWorker) returning damaged/blank pdf

Tags: pdf, itext, httpresponse, xmlworker

Not sure if I skipped a step in my code, I am using ItextSharp version 5.5.1 and XML Worker version 5.5.1. The doc.Close throws an exception "the document has no pages", but I watched sw.toString (it has the html content).

```
private void ExporttoPDF()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=RequestSummaryReport.pdf");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);         

            var doc = new Document(PageSize.A3, 45, 5, 5, 5);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);

            doc.Open();

            HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
            htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
            ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);

            IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer)));

            XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
            XMLParser xmlParse = new XMLParser(true, worker);

            pnlReport.RenderControl(htw);
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
            xmlParse.Parse(sr);
            xmlParse.Flush();
            doc.Close();
            Response.Write(doc);
        }
```

Comment: At first look it seems mostly correct. You are writing directly to the HTTP response stream so there's no need to do `Response.Write(doc);` (that line doesn't do what most people assume it does anyway). I don't have an ASP.Net server on hand so I tried it with `StringReader sr = new StringReader("<strong>Hello</strong>");` and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent almost two hours with the same symptoms, and finally figured out the cause of the problem. I'm guessing you may have figured it out already (since, the question was asked 5 months ago) but I thought I'd post the answer in case there are others who run into the same problem.

When you create your `PdfWriter`, you pass in the stream (in your case `Response.OutputStream`) which is to be the destination for the generated PDF content. When as the `PdfWriter` writes content to the stream, the stream position is incremented accordingly. When the writer finishes, the stream position is at the end of the content, and this makes sense because any further calls to write should continue where the `PdfWriter` left off.

The problem is that when the MVC pipeline takes the `Response.OutputStream` (after your method returns) and attempts to read it to send its contents to the client (or in general, whenever the PDF destination stream is consumed), the stream position is at the end of the content, and that means that to the consumer it appears that the stream is empty, hence the empty PDF output.

To solve this, simply reset the the position of the stream immediate after you are finished writing to it, and before anything tries to read from it. In your case insert:

```
Response.OutputStream.Position = 0;
```

right after the line with `xmlParse.Flush()`, since that is the last line that will write to the stream.